# Android: Why size and quality of pictures is worse using Camera.takePicture than using native application?

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing my own application to take pictures, and I see the result is very poor comparing with the pictures I can take with the native application of the phone.

I'm using the camera API of Android and setting the biggest width and height available in the list;

```
List<Camera.Size> SupportedSizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes(); 
BestSizePicture = SupportedSizes.get(0);    
param.setPictureSize(BestSizePicture.width, BestSizePicture.height);
camera.setParameters(param);
camera.takePicture(null, null, mJPGPictureCallback);
```

With my app I'm able to get .JPG pictures of no more than 400kb, and with the native app normally are around 2Mb, resulting in a much higher quality.

Another issue I found is when I call:

```
List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

I see the bigges dimension able is 1280x1024, when I have taken pictures with the native app of 2592x1944.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or what setting should I modify to get with my application results similar to the native "Camara" app of my phone?

Further information:
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running in Android 4.3

Comment: The Android Camera API has problems with focus from device to device, in particular I have had problems with building an app that uses the camera with Samsung devices :\